# Loading jquery from google doesn't work (for me)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ah the wretched noob I am, the following html document doesn't alert anyone of my cry for help.  Anyone know why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Somebody please help me.');
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using and where is this page located (i.e. is it a standalone .htm file you're opening in the browser, testing on localhost, Internet hosted?)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Somebody please help me.');
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Just fixed the `src` in the `script` tag.

**Edit:** Actually, the original syntax would work fine if you load the page in a non-local context. Leaving out the protocol implies that the 'current' protocol would be used depending on whether resources are loaded over `http` or `https`. Loading it locally implies that the script is loaded from `file:///ajax.googleapis.com/....`, which obviously won't resolve to anything. See [here](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) for more information. Thanks to @PetrolMan for pointing to the HTML 5 boiler plate site.

Comment: Ah... cool.  I copy/pasted that script line from http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ I wonder why he doesn't have the "http:"?!

Comment: @Sudhir - I had tried too... it was fixed so quickly that SO wouldn't let me accept the answer!

Answer (score 3):

That same syntax is used in the HTML5 Boilerplate:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
```

not

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `http:` in front of the url in the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Somebody please help me.');
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The source is jacked up. Use

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible values for the Src Attribute are

•An absolute URL - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/example.js")
•A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like src="/scripts/example.js")

So you should have your URL as http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js