# Javascript/Jquery Doesn't Function Locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I keep having this issue with many different code snippets in JQuery where the code I try works on sites like JSFiddle and w3schools, but doesn't work on my computer when I just try to load an html file through Chrome.

My question is, to run JQuery locally, do you need compiling software like you would need with C, or should it work like HTML/CSS does with just a browser?

Here's an example of some simple code that works in JSFiddle and w3schools but doesn't work for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, if a compiler is required. Can you recommend one to me? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: A compiler isn't necessary, but I would guess you're opening the file directly, rather than using a webserver on your local machine. This confuses Chrome, which uses the `file:` protocol to load jQuery, which is wrong as it should be HTTP. You can fix this by specifying `http://` in your script src, or by using a webserver.

Comment: What are the issues you are seeing? Any errors in the console or failed requests in the network tab? If you are trying to do things that involve canvas, FileReader, or other more "advanced" HTMl5-ish things, they typically don't work on the `file:///` protocol. To get around that I typically just do `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in my root directory and then navigate to `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading jquery from google doesn't work (for me)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875936/loading-jquery-from-google-doesnt-work-for-me)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does no jQuery work on my home machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509740/why-does-no-jquery-work-on-my-home-machine)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, using the // syntax doesn't work when you're running through the local file system - it looks for `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Obviously that file doesn't exist and jQuery isn't loaded on the page. You need to specify it as an HTTP(s) resource if you're going to open it locally:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `http:` like this -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```