# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function javascript datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my partial view.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartDate").datepicker();
  }); 
</script> 
<div class="col-xs-20 no-padding section">
  <label for="StartDate" class="">Form:</label>
  <input type="text" name="StrtDate" id="StartDate" />
</div>
```

It gives me error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** .Kindly tell me what i am missing.

Comment: When do you get that error? When you call `$("#StartDate").datepicker();`?

Comment: Your code works on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6mq2M/1/

Comment: when i run the page in browser,its give me that error.I think so,i am missing some reference,but not know which one.

Comment: Check you browser for errors. The path to the js files may be incorrect

Comment: Yes it works on fiddle but not on my browser .Path to .js is online.

Comment: Do not use `//` locally. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875936/loading-jquery-from-google-doesnt-work-for-me

Comment: @undefined it give error on removing //.the error is in function :**Object doesn't support property or method**

Comment: @MuhammadAli You need to provide the `http:` protocol along with `//`. Like this `http://`

Comment: @RahilWazir it gives me same error after using your suggestion